# File download from API to Meteor server and upload to S3

Tags: meteor, amazon-s3, collectionfs

I am sending a request from my Meteor server to download a file via an API. I then want to upload that file to S3. I keep getting the following *"NoSuchKey: The specified key does not exist."* I initially thought it was maybe a problem with my AcessKey/SecretKey form AWS but after googling this for a while the only examples I could find of other people getting this error is when trying to download a file from S3.

**Setting up cfs:s3**

```
var imageStore = new FS.Store.S3("images", {

  accessKeyId: "MyAcessKeyId", //required if environment variables are not set
  secretAccessKey: "MySecretAcessKey", //required if environment variables are not set
  bucket: "BucketName", //required

});

Images = new FS.Collection("images", {
  stores: [imageStore]
});
```

**Start file transfer from API and upload to S3**

```
client.get_result(id, Meteor.bindEnvironment(function(err, result){ //result is the download stream and id specifies which file to download.
  if (err !== null){
    return;
  } 
   var file = new FS.File(result);
   Images.insert(file, function (err, fileObj) {
    if (err){
      console.log(err);
    }

  });
}));
```

**Note:** I was getting the following error so I added Meteor.bindEnvironment.
*"Meteor code must always run within a Fiber. Try wrapping callbacks that you pass to non-Meteor libraries with Meteor.bindEnvironment."*

**Node.js example from API Documentation**

```
client.get_result(id, function(err, result){
        if (err != null) {            
            return;
        }

        file.writeFile(path.join('public', path.join('results', filename)), result, 'binary');
    });
```

Comment: Did you find solution for this. I am trying to do exactly the same thing.

Comment: I did. I can't remember what it was off the top of my head. I will see if I can dig it up when I get into work tomorrow.

Comment: @technoguff Just added the answer that fixed the error for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What ended up fixing the problem for me was moving part of the setup to the lib folder. Although I tried several different ways I was unable to get it to execute entirely on the server. It looks like the documentation was updated recently which states everything a bit more clearly. If you follow this setup it should eliminate the error. See the section titled **Client, Server, and S3 credentials**

https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-CollectionFS/tree/master/packages/s3

Note: Make sure not to place you secret key is not in you lib folder as this is accessible from the client.